# Is it possible to create workflow to create wiki page from word?

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki-pages

I'm very new to sharepoint and starting to discover things. Is it possible to create wiki page from word? and show those to diff. selected user each wiki pages?

Answer (score 0):

With a little trickery, you can publish Word content to a wiki page by connecting it via a blog posting first.

- Open your Word document
- Save it as docx if it is an old doc
- Publish the document to a SharePoint Blog 
  *Note: the pictures included in the Word document will be uploaded to the Blog picture library! So do not delete the Blog site later, and make sure your Wiki visitors can read items from the picture library.*
- Open the Blog entry in your browser and click on the Edit Button
- Copy the whole entry
- Paste the clipboard to a Wiki page

For more information, check [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.hezser.de/blog/2009/03/17/publish-word-documents-to-a-sharepoint-wiki/amp/)